# Type error: Argument of type 'IParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IParams'. - Typescript | NextJS14

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, parameters

**I got this error in my code I am using Prisma Next js 14 and typescript I got this error while tyring to load my product details using product ID In bottom screenshot also have this error**

```
Failed to compile.
./app/product/[productId]/page.tsx:13:40
Type error: Argument of type 'IParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IParams'.
  Types of property 'productId' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  11 |
  12 | const Product = async ({ params }: { params: IParams }) => {
> 13 |   const product = await getProductById(params);
     |                                        ^
  14 |
  15 |   if (!product)
  16 |     return <NullData title="OOPS! Product with given ID does not exist" />;
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

**this is my getProductById file**

```
import  prisma  from '@/libs/prismadb';

interface IParams {
  productId: string; 
}

export default async function getProductById(params: IParams) {
  try {
    const { productId } = params;
    const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({
        where:{
            id: productId
        },
        include:{
            reviews:{
                include:{
                    user: true
                },
                orderBy:{
                    createdDate: 'desc'
                }
            }
        }
    })
    if(!product){
        return null;
    }
    return product;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

**And this is my page which this error got**

```
import Container from "@/app/components/Container";
import ProductDetails from "./productDetails";
import ListRatings from "./ListRatings";
import getProductById from "@/actions/getProductById";
import NullData from "@/app/components/NullData";

interface IParams {
  productId?: string;
}


const Product = async ({ params }: { params: IParams }) => {
  const product = await getProductById(params);

  if (!product)
    return <NullData title="OOPS! Product with given ID does not exist" />;

  return (
    <div className="p-8">
      <Container>
        <ProductDetails product={product} />
        <div className="flex flex-col mt-20 gap-4">
          <div>Add Rating</div>
          <ListRatings product={product} />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

**Please help me to fix this error and this is my folder structure.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well simply, you have 2 interfaces called IParams.
The one in the getProductById file has one attribute called productId which is a string.
The one in your component file also has one attribute called productId but this time it is a string or `undefined` (see the '?').

The problem basically is that you are giving a `string | undefined` where a `string` is expected.

What you can do is :

- remove the '?' in your component file but that would make the attribute required for this component
- or check productId isn't undefined before passing params to getProductById
- name your interfaces differently in order to avoid the confusion

Also, why are you passing a IParams object to getProductById then extracting productId from it ? Why not passing `productId` directly ?

Answer (score 1):

You've defined two interfaces with the same name `IParams`.
Both have one property `productId`, but in your second interface you defined `productId` as optional (used `?` sign).
Decide which type do you need (one with optional or the other) and the type error will be fixed.